# How do I import a CSV containing text representations of GUIDs into sqlite an store them as 16 bytes?

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, csv

I have a CSV export of data from SQL Server.

It contains two fields, Key and Value.

So the CSV contains:

```
Key,Value
576EEFCC-A3E1-4CDA-8E6F-E1A9C062C497,Kevin
```

and many more.

I can import CSV files with SQLite Expert into a table with matching GUID and TEXT fields.

I think I've confirmed that it's being stored as 36 bytes not 16 bytes (SQLite Expert's BLOB editor shows 36 bytes)

If it has been written as a string, how can I import it as 16 bytes or convert the content to 16 bytes?

Comment: I do not think you can store 36 bytes in 16 byte field without truncating the data. Maybe some sort of compression can be performed on the data.

Comment: @Wexoni GUIDs actually contain 16 bytes of information.

Comment: SQL Server is storing 16 bytes in a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER field (GUID)
However it stores it in the exported CSV file as a 36 byte string representation.
SQLite Expert then imports this as-is into the Key field.
It works, I get a GUID back but internally it's being stored as a 36 byte blob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV files always contain strings, so the contents will be imported as strings.

Importing blobs is difficult without using [blob literals](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue).
Use a good editor or write a script to convert the input file into a series of SQL commands, like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(x'0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF', 'Kevin');
```

Comment: Maybe if I format the output in the CSV to be x'data' it'll take the hint

Comment: Yes it does, I forgot the single quotes!

Comment: @RoboJ1M If you have a different answer, write it as an answer.